# zendframe work with ubuntu 11

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, php

I have download the zendframe work v 1.11.5 on ubuntu 11 (every thing else is installed) after putting the command zf create project /var/www/name it gives me a lot of warnings,so how to set up the zend frame work properly..
the warning:

> Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your
> VHOST, please see docs/README
>
> PHP
> Warning:
> require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in
> /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on
> line 46 PHP Stack trace:

Answer (score 3):

I know the solution,the problem is with phpUnit and pear ,if any one try to install phpUnit from the repository then he will got the warning above,so you need to install it by pear.

try in the terminal:

```
pear channel-discover components.ez.no

pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

however you will another probelm after doing line 3 because you need to upgrade pear so do this before line 3:

```
sudo pear upgrade
```

then DO Step 3 again

```
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

of course you need also to set the path in php.ini try(locate `php.ini`)

then in the file file add these :

```
include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php/PHPunit:/usr/share/php/PEAR"
```

notice the path to pear and PHPUnit, so if your path different you have to locate your path ;)

hope thats help :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the any web directory say, /var/www/html/test

Now call the zf.sh file in the bin folder of zend framework to create new project

In my case I extracted the zend framework in /var/ww/html/zend-framework

So I called the zf.sh file as follows

/var/www/html/zend-framework/bin/zf.sh create project zendtest

Now a project called called “ zendtest “  has been created in the current directory. This project will have four Sub folders.

Now we need to include the Libraries in the zend framework in our new project. To do that, just copy the folder called Zend from the library folder of our zend framework.  (in my case I copied /var/ww/html/zend-framework/library/Zend ).

That’s all, we have created a sample  project in Zend framework. We can test it using browsing the Public folder in the new project

http://localhost/ test/zendtest/public/